# WP plugin or strategy recommendation for learning plans and prerequisites

Tags: wordpress, sequence

My use case is to display information about 50 educational courses such that end users know what they can and should sign up for. Currently I have created the "Courses" as a post type, with all required info, opportunity to tag and categorize etc.

My issue is that I need to logically display these courses several collections as "learning plans", such that the courses need to be taken in a certain order depending on user role and product.

So for example, if an **engineer** wants to learn about **subject A**, I need to show that they must take:

1. Course A
2. Course C
3. Course D
4. Course F
5. Course K

If an **operator** wants to learn about **subject B**, I need to show they must take:

1. Course A
2. Course B
3. Course D

*Note that this functionality is all for logical display, I do not actually need the course content or completions or whatever.*

What is the best way to logically group courses and display these learning plans based on dynamically selected user role and subject interest in Wordpress? Is there a recommended plugin that would provide this functionality in general for groups and sequencing? I have been searching for several days but have found no good options that fit this use case.